# Winforms сворачивается не корректно

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь свернуть форму в трей, а сворачивается и остается табом над "пуском".

Прячу так:

```cs
private void UCE_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("resize");
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {                
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Мессагу воткнул, чтобы посмотреть вообще ловит ли момент ресайза, как оказалось не ловит. Срабатывает только при запуске, дальше нет. `FormBorderStyle` перепробовал все. Пнете в нужном направлении? Спасибо!

[image: некорректная форма]

Comment: [пнул](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625426/12888024)

Comment: Увы. Решение то же по сути. Проблема не в том, чтобы спрятать notifyIcon - проблема в том, что вся эта история - private void UCE_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)  срабатывает только один раз, на запуске....

Comment: Значит ваш вопрос не содержит информации о проблеме, которую вы решаете. Покажите, где вы подписываете данный обработчик на событие `Form.Resize`.

Comment: Так и не понял в чем была проблема... видимо что-то где-то жестко напутал, хотя в трех строчках заблудиться - это талант. Помимо ресайза не отрабатывались нажатия на кнопки формы. Просто пересоздал Form1.Designer.cs скопипастив содержимое и все заработало как надо... если бы вы не упомянули события, я бы не начал их перетрясать... спасибо!